# GitHubActions Runner Error: Command failed: go env GOPATH

Tags: github-actions

We have GitHubActions and we run it in an Centos Server. We have set the root's .bashrc as `export GOROOT=/opt/go export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin`
In the Github Actions we have the file:

```yaml
    setup:
    needs: cleanup
    name: Setup
    runs-on: [self-hosted, Linux, X64, CentOS-Linux-7.9]
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
   - name: Set up Go 1.17
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
         go-version: 1.17
    #      id: Go
      - run: go version
        
       
      - name: Checkout code into go module directory
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

When Github Actions runs this , it throws the error:

```
0s
Run actions/setup-go@v2
  with:
    go-version: 1.17
    stable: true
    token: ***
 ...
Setup go stable version spec 1.17
Found in cache @ /opt/actions-runner/_work/_tool/go/1.17.11/x64
Added go to the path
missing $GOPATH
Error: Command failed: go env GOPATH
missing $GOPATH
```

Can someone please help with this error?
The Go installation is working and on the Linux box as root '`go version`' works.

Comment: Sorry the formatting of yaml did not work correctly in the question
- name: Set up Go 1.17
        uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
         go-version: 1.17
    #      id: Go
      - run: go version
               
      - name: Checkout code into go module directory
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but with github hosted runners, i'm using the already available workflow -  "Build a Go project."

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [`actions/setup-go` issue 116](https://github.com/actions/setup-go/issues/116) which includes:

> I believe the reason of issue is missing $HOME variable on the self-hosted runners.
>
> The missing `HOME` variable makes it so that Go is not able to make default folders for `GOPATH` and `GOCACHE` and such.

So double-check what `echo $HOME` displays in your runner.

---

The [OP AwsGeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15994649/awsgeek) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73422886/githubactions-runner-error-command-failed-go-env-gopath/73423327#comment129670863_73423327):

> First as suggested I did an `echo $HOME` and it was empty and under the env: I added the value for home env: `HOME: "/home/xxxx-account"`

Comment: Thanks @VonC for the quick reply. Yes that solved the issue.
First as suggested I did an echo $HOME and it was empty and under the env: I added the value for home
env:
HOME: "/home/xxxx-account"

Comment: @AwsGeek Great, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.